# How to get the absolute path of all files in a Git repository with submodules?

Tags: git, path, git-submodules, absolute-path, git-ls-files

I am trying to list all untracked files in all submodules recursively:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --full-name
```

But this does not list the absolute path, it gives the relative path to the submodule's folder.

How should I modify my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191500/3503228) for the idea. This works:

```
git submodule foreach --quiet 'a=$(printf "$(git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --full-name|sed "s~^~$(pwd)/~")"; printf x); a=${a%x}; echo "$a"' | sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

Answer (score 4):

(Note: this is a "tool" answer, not a "solution" answer.  That is, this answer is meant to give you the tools you will need to *construct* the solution you want.)

Use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the absolute path to the current repository.  Do this while in the superproject, of course.  That gives you the first part of any path prefix—but now you'll need the remaining part.

As [the `git submodule` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) says, in a `foreach`, you have access to several variables, including `$path`:

> `$path` is the name of the submodule directory relative to the superproject ...

What's not immediately clear (you will have to test this yourself) is whether `$path` is cumulative in the case of recursive submodules.  That is, if superproject A has submodule B under path `top/subB`, `$path` will be `top/subB` when you're in submodule B.  But suppose submodule B acts as a superproject to submodule C, with B's own path being `contained/C`.  Will `$path` be `top/subB/contained/C` when inside submodule C, or will it be only `contained/C`?<sup>1</sup>

In any case, once you have the appropriate prefix, just use something like `sed` to tack it on the front, e.g.,:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --full-name | sed "s,^,$prefix,"
```

where `$prefix` is set to the appropriate prefix, which might just be `$path/`.  (This assumes none of your file names contain an embedded newline; if they do, your original command is in trouble anyway.  As written, it also assumes none of your prefixes contains a comma—if they do, use a character other than `,`, or make `$prefix` quote the commas with backslashes.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Logic suggests it will be the complete path; the relative path is not entirely usable without knowing how many submodules have been recursed-into.  However, the relative path is easier to produce.

Comment: You mentioned, " Will $path be top/subB/contained/C when inside submodule C, or will it be only contained/C?". But to resolve this ambiguity I have asked for complete absolute path.

Comment: You can pass, to your `foreach`, the path to the top level superproject (`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`). But you'll still have to resolve the above question (I don't know the answer) to decide how to work with `$path`. I would hope that `$path` is always relative to the top level superproject, not the immediate superproject, but I have not verified this. Assuming `$path` is relative to the top superproject, set `prefix` appropriately: `prefix="$abs/$path/"` where `$abs` is already set to the output from `$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)`.